# Best approach to backup and migrate Boot Camp

Tags: time-machine, bootcamp, windows, vmware, migration

I have a boot camp install which I also use from VMware fusion (for when I can't be bothered to reboot!) and I need to migrate from MacBook Air to a MacBook Pro.

Obviously time machine makes migrating a Mac a breeze... but any thoughts on Boot Camp? I don't have much on there but really don't fancy wasting time setting it up again. Although I would appreciate being able to increase the partition size.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to migrate a Boot Camp partition is to make an image of the partition and then restore that image to a blank partition.

Use Disk Utility to make an image of the BOOTCAMP partition, then repartition as 2 partitions<sup>1</sup>. Make sure that the BOOTCAMP partition is the same size or larger than before, then use the Restore tab to restore the image to the partition.

<sup><sup>1</sup> The repartitioning can be done with either Disk Utility or Boot Camp Assistant.</sup>